# What is the proper way to extend a class in another file?

Tags: php, class, require, extends

This is what I have in foo.php

```
class Foo
{
    public $foo = NULL;
    public $foo2 = NULL;

    public function setFoo ($foo, $foo2)
    {
       $this->foo = $foo;
       $this->foo2 = $foo2'
    }
}
```

This is what I have in foo3.php

```
class Foo3 extends Foo
{
    public $foo3 = NULL;

    public function setFoo3 ($foo3)
    {
       $this->foo = $foo3;
    }
}
```

This is how I require it in my third file run.php:

```
require_once "foo.php";
require_once "foo3.php";
$foo = new Foo();
$foo->setFoo3("hello");
```

I get this error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined method Foo::setFoo3()

I'm not sure if the problem is how I'm requiring them. Thanks.

Comment: i don't see any "extend" keyword in this. Check: http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.extends.php

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your example, you are instantiating `Foo`, which is the parent and has no knowledge of the method `setFoo3()`. Try this:

```
class Foo3 extends Foo
{
    ...
}

require_once "foo.php";
require_once "foo3.php";
$foo = new Foo3();
$foo->setFoo3("hello");
```

Comment: if i do not require_once "foo.php" in the Foo3 file, it still works. Is it good practice to require the file that I am extending? I assume it would be.

Comment: Short answer yes. Long answer, autoloading (http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php).

Answer (score 11):

At the first, in your *foo.php* shouldn't mark your fields `public`, because you set those values inside `setFoo($foo1, $foo2)` method. Instead, you may have something like:

```
<?php

class Foo
{
    private $foo1;
    private $foo2;

    public function setFoo($foo1, $foo2) {
        $this->foo1 = $foo1;
        $this->foo2 = $foo2;
    }
 }
```

Then you should add `extends` keyword when declaring class `Foo3`, and another thing you need to include extending class file in the beginning of the file. In your case you may have something like the following in your *foo3.php* file:

```
<?php

require_once "foo.php";

class Foo3 extends Foo
{
    public function setFoo3($foo3) {
        $this->setFoo($foo3, "some foo3 specific value"); // calling superclass method
    }
}
```

then you can create an instantiate of a `Foo3` class in your *run.php* like so:

```
<?php

require_once "foo3.php";

$foo3 = new Foo3();
$foo3->setFoo3("bar");
```

and my advice, you should read a little about OOP techniques ;)

Comment: Thanks ;) Is there a specific reason not to do "$this->foo = $foo3;" but to do the super class method?

Comment: Nope, you can if you need. Think how to design your classes, for example a `Person` class instead of your `Foo` can contain a fields that describes common person properties. In this case a subclasses (all those extending `Person` class) you may have, are for example `Teacher` and `Student` each containing properties that is specific for his needs.

Answer (score 1):

Of course that doesn't work.  You've created a `Foo` object, and then tried to call `foo3` on it.  But `Foo` doesn't have a `foo3` method.