# How to override function in laravel 5.4 vendor?

Tags: php, laravel

I am using the [elFinder package](https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder). Please help me to override the `sanitizeFileName` method in Laravel

```
vendor\studio-42\elfinder\php\plugins\Sanitizer\plugin.php
```

Here is the method:

```php
private function sanitizeFileName($filename, $opts, $allows = array())
{
    $targets = $allows? array_diff($opts['targets'], $allows) : $opts['targets'];
    return str_replace($targets, $opts['replace'], $filename);
}
```

Comment: Posting an image to share code is a bad idea. Stack Overflow provides [a nice way to add code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) to your question.

Comment: @louisfischer: thanks you, i post image to easy see my question.

Comment: It is not easy to read or see at all. Write or copy/paste the function directly in your question. You can even reference [the class from the GitHub repository](https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/blob/master/php/plugins/Sanitizer/plugin.php).

Comment: You could fork the package, do the changes and load your version. Composer documentation for [loading a package from a VCS repository](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs). From docs: __If you are using a certain library for your project and you decide to change something in the library, you will want your project to use the patched version__

Answer (score 0):

You can override it by inheriting the class then write the exact method inside your class. Like so:

```
class MyClass extends Plugin{

  private function sanitizeFileName($filename, $opts, $allows = array()){
   // your code here...
  }

}
```

If you're having an issue with the visibility, use `protected`/`public` instead.

**Update:** *Extending class*

[What is the proper way to extend a class in another file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088832/what-is-the-proper-way-to-extend-a-class-in-another-file)

http://php.net/manual/it/keyword.extends.php

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php

Comment: but this plugin has "-" character (studio-42)

I don't know how to extends it and use this path

Ex: 

class MyClass extends studio-42\elfinder\php\plugins\Sanitizer\elFinderPluginSanitizer {}

Comment: What do you mean by "but this plugin has "-" character" ?

Comment: do you see picture in my post.

Plugin name is studio-42 (vendor\studio-42\elfinder\php\plugins\Sanitizer\plugin.php)

I don't know how to extends this plugin

Comment: Don't forget to check the check mark if it solves your problem. And for your future questions, if they solved your question :)